# xmgrace: Logarithmic histogram binwidths

Tags: xmgrace

I have been creating histograms in xmgrace. Some of the bins at the tail end of the histogram are empty, so I want to use logarithmically spaced bins, where the binwidths at the start are very narrow and then become very large (under logarithmic scale, the bin spaces would show up even).

I tried doing this with "abscissas of another set" option in the xmgrace histogram interface, but all that does is if I created a file with logarithmic bin edges for 500 total bins,  it gives me 500 evenly spaced bins.

So how can I have variable bin widths in xmgrace histogram?

Answer (score 0):

*Abscissas of another set* is the way to go. Create/Import another `set` (say `G0.S2`) of type `XY` with the desired logarithmic bin edges as its *abscissa* (`X` column). The values in `Y` column are not relevant. Here is an example set with 5 non-uniform bin edges.

[image: NewSet]

Use this set to create a histogram from your original set (say `G0.S0`) as

[image: Histogram]